# Comparing records and get the differences as text

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table 1**

```
+------+-----+-----+
| Name | RID | SID |
+------+-----+-----+
| A    |   1 |   9 |
| B    |   2 |   8 |
| C    |   3 |   7 |
| D    |   4 |   6 |
+------+-----+-----+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------+-----+-----+
| Name | RID | SID |
+------+-----+-----+
| A    |   1 |   9 |
| B    |   4 |   8 |
| C    |   3 |   7 |
| D    |   4 |   9 |
+------+-----+-----+
```

I want to compare the values in both tables and get the output as below. I was able to find the mismatch records using  **EXCEPT** but unable to get in my expected format.

```
+------+-------------+
| Name |    Diff     |
+------+-------------+
| B    | RID: 2 -> 8 |
| D    | SID: 6 -> 9 |
+------+-------------+
```

I have tried below:

```
Select Name ,  RID, SID from Table1
Except
Select Name ,  RID, SID from Table2
```

Comment: Your attempt is needed. Did you even try something like a `JOIN` and filtering the data?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: looks like a simple `JOIN` of the 2 tables with the condition you want in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Can u explain this Output,How it needs to Work? --@Santhosh

Comment: @Thiyagu The query should compare all the fields and in case of differences should return  old value and new value along with name in the sample format mentioned above.

Comment: ""Unable to get my expected format" - this is called programming. Write a program that does this comparison and gnerates your format. YOu show zero attempt - your "attempt" is like "I plan to cook a 5 star meal" and showing "I opened the kitchen door" - off topic.

Comment: @TomTom I totally agree with you but at this point of time my mind was stuck and I needed a solution badly so posted it the way I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to get your desired results. It `JOIN`s `Table1` and `Table2` on any rows which have different `RID` or `SID` values for a given `Name`, and then uses `CONCAT_WS` (available since version 2017) to get the desired `Diff` value. Note this code will also deal with the case where *both* `RID` and `SID` are different:

```
SELECT t1.Name,
       CONCAT_WS(', ',
                 CASE WHEN t1.RID != t2.RID THEN CONCAT('RID: ', t1.RID, ' -> ', t2.RID) END,
                 CASE WHEN t1.SID != t2.SID THEN CONCAT('SID: ', t1.SID, ' -> ', t2.SID) END
                 ) AS Diff
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Name = t1.Name 
              AND (t2.RID != t1.RID OR t2.SID != t1.SID)
```

If you're running SQL Server prior to 2017 and don't have `CONCAT_WS`, you can use this query which just uses `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT t1.Name,
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN t1.RID != t2.RID THEN CONCAT('RID: ', t1.RID, ' -> ', t2.RID) END,
              CASE WHEN t1.RID != t2.RID AND t1.SID != t2.SID THEN ', ' END,
              CASE WHEN t1.SID != t2.SID THEN CONCAT('SID: ', t1.SID, ' -> ', t2.SID) END
              ) AS Diff
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Name = t1.Name 
              AND (t2.RID != t1.RID OR t2.SID != t1.SID)
```

Output (for my expanded demo):

```
Name    Diff
B       RID: 2 -> 4
D       SID: 6 -> 9
E       RID: 4 -> 6, SID: 6 -> 7
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69b48/4)

Comment: Could you share the `CONCAT_WS` function pls

Comment: @Santosh it's part of SQL Server 2017 and up. If you're not using that,  see my edit for a version that only uses CONCAT.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I am using old version 2012 and so the function not recognized. The updated answer works and made my life easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f21ef/5).

```
select
  t1.name,
  case 
    when
      t1.rid != t2.rid
    then 
      concat('RID: ', t1.rid, '->', t1.sid) 
    else
      concat('SID: ', t1.rid, '->', t1.sid)
  end
  as diff
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.name = t2.name

where t1.rid != t2.rid
or t1.sid != t2.sid
```

Output:

```
| Name |    Diff     |
+------+-------------+
| B    | RID: 2 -> 8 |
| D    | SID: 6 -> 9 |
```